# How to check if file has enough variables?

Tags: c++, file, file-io

I am currently learning how to implement files in my code and need to know how to check if a users imputed file contains enough variables for the program to work? I receive a file from the user and then have to error check it. Here is what I have so far to input the file and then check if it can be opened. All I need now is to see if the file is valid, for it is using two Classes defined earlier.

```
int main()
{
    string vectorFile;
    string matrixFile;
    string resultFile;

    cout<<"Enter vector filename: "<<endl;
    cin>>vectorFile;
    cout<<"Enter matrix filename: "<<endl;
    cin>>matrixFile;
    cout<<"Enter result filename: "<<endl;
    cin>>resultFile;
    cout<<""<<endl;

    ifstream finV;
    ifstream finM;
    ofstream fout;

    finV.open(vectorFile.c_str());
    finM.open(matrixFile.c_str());
    fout.open(resultFile.c_str());


    if(finV.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Unable to open vector file.";
        return 1;
    }

    if(finM.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Unable to open matrix file.";
        return 1;
    }

    if(fout.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Unable to open vector file.";
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you need to do a separate check before processing it? Typically, you just process it and if you encounter an error during processing, then you report that the file contents are incorrect.

Comment: 1) Read until you have enough values or reading fails. 2) Check if you read enough. It's as easy and boring as that.

Comment: Oh, and don't use `using namespace std`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether or not enough values have been read in by utilizing the ">>" operator.

```
double value;
if (!(finv >> value)) {
    cout << "Unable to read vector file." << endl;
    return 0;
} else {
    //Set value in array, vector, etc.
}
```